# Finding the formula for the nth partial product

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the formula for the nth partial product of $\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k+1)-2}{k(k+1)}$.

So $\prod\limits_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k(k+1)-2}{k(k+1)} = \frac{2(2+1)-2}{2(2+1)}\cdot\frac{3(3+1)-2}{3(3+1)}\cdot \frac{4(4+1)-2}{4(4+1)} \cdot \frac{5(5+1)-2}{5(5+1)}\cdot \frac{6(6+1)-2}{6(6+1)}  \cdots = $

$\frac{4}{6}\cdot\frac{10}{12}\cdot\frac{18}{20}\cdot\frac{28}{30}\cdot\frac{40}{42}\cdots = $

$\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot\frac{40}{3}\cdots=$

$\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{8}{3}\cdots=$

$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdots$

Then looking at $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n\frac{k(k+1)-2}{k(k+1)}$.

$n=2$:  $\frac{2}{3}$

$n=3$:  $\frac{5}{9}$

$n=4$:  $\frac{1}{2}$

$n=5$:  $\frac{7}{15}$

$n=6$:  $\frac{4}{9}$

I'm really struggling to find the pattern that will reveal the nth partial product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$k(k+1)-2=k^2+k-2=(k+2)(k-1)$$
we have
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{k(k+1)-2}{k(k+1)}&=\prod_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(k+2)(k-1)}{k(k+1)}\\\\&=\frac{\prod (k+2)\prod(k-1)}{\prod k\prod (k+1)}\\\\&=\frac{((n+2)!/3!)(n-1)!}{n!\ (n+1)!/2!}\\\\&=\frac{n+2}{3n}\end{align}$$